# Fill polygons with different colours in gmt6

Tags: polygon, gmt

I want to plot in gmt6 different polygons filled with different colours according to their attribute. The file containing this info starts like this:

```
 @VGMT1.0 @GPOLYGON
 @R-180/180/-89.999/90                                                   
 @Je4326
 @Jp"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
 @Jw"GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AXIS[\"Latitude\",NORTH],AXIS[\"Longitude\",EAST],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]"
 @Nid|prov_name|prov_type|prov_ref|prov_group|lastorogen|continent|conjugate1|comment|crust_type|conjugate2|area
 @Tdouble|string|string|string|string|string|string|string|string|string|string|double
 FEATURE_DATA

 @D1|"Gariep Belt"|"orogenic belt"|doi:10.1144/jgs2012-059||"East African"|Africa|||continental||42470.307130531022267
 @P
17.0605506952188 -29.7892761477971
17.0258370972184 -30.4040298713381
16.8618462006242 -30.0682389878355
```

The attribute in this case is `prov_type` (defined for the first case in the line below the > symbol).

Which gmt command should I use here and how?